# Generate an incremental SPARQL query

Tags: java, sparql, dbpedia

is there any way to generate a SPARQL query  in a dynamic way?
what I'm trying to do is some thing like this:
if I have a DBpedia resource r1 and another DBpedia resource r2, 
this query

```
SELECT * WHERE { <r1> ?pre <r2> }
```

will return the predicate between the 2 resources
and this query

```
SELECT * WHERE { <r1> ?pre1 ?obj1 . ?obj1 ?pre2 <r2> }
```

will return all the predicates and object between these two resources ( in two steps)
and so on
I'm trying to build this query in such a way that it will automatically increase the number of objects and predicates between the two resources (for example in 4 steps)?

Comment: Do you want multiple queries? Or you want one query that encapsulates this pattern for a given depth?  Or what?  It's not quite clear what you're trying to get.

Comment: if I write 5 SPARQL queries to retrieve up to 5 relations between any two resources.. it will be a time consuming. I'm thinking some thing like that: if the two resources has one direction relation, return it, else, if there is a middle object between the two resources, return the middle object and its predicates with the two resources... and so on

Comment: OK, so you want one query that returns the shortest path, so to speak.  SPARQL property paths would be a nice candidate here, except that they don't provide a mechanism for extracting intermediate node, or for using variables in the path.  I think you might have to use something with **union** or **optional** and writing out the different options manually. Is there any chance that you might be able to ignore the predicates?  That might make the problem easier.

Comment: Another question:  do you anticipate there being paths of different lengths between r1 and r2?  If there's only path, then you can get it fairly easily regardless of the length.

Comment: both of the intermediate nodes and the predicates are very important in my work. while I was searching I found something that seems to be like what I'm looking for, except that is was written in action script I think, so I really don't get it that clear

Comment: @user3293838 in [this followup question you posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065884/cant-get-any-results-from-this-sparql-query) you mention that you have found a solution to this problem. Could you post your solution here as an answer so that this question become useful for others with a similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out how to solve this problem..
here is my solution:

```
private String completeQuery(String coreQuery){
String completeQuery = "";
completeQuery += "SELECT * WHERE {"+ "\n";
completeQuery += coreQuery + "\n";
completeQuery =completeQuery + "}" + "\n" +"limit 5" ;
return completeQuery;}
public String link(String object1, String object2, int distance){
if(distance == 1){
    String Quer = "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/"+object1+">" + " ?pre1 " +"<http://dbpedia.org/resource/"+object2+">";
    return completeQuery(Quer);
} 
else {
    String query = "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/"+object1+">" + " ?pre1 ?obj1 " + ".\n";
    for(int i = 1; i < distance-1; i++){
        query += "?obj" + i + " ?pre" + (i+1) + " ?obj" + (i+1) + ".\n" ;

    }
    query  += "?obj" + (distance-1) + " ?pre" + distance + " " + "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/"+object2+">";
    return completeQuery(query);
}}
```